# PANDAS: Slice pandas series n rows into the past with a datetime index

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, series

`upper_lower_bound` returns 2 datetime indices from my dataframe. I only use one at a time and they have no relation to each other.

I want to get the `max()` value of the previous 6 rows data from a dataframe `highP` but I get an error if I try to subtract 6 from it. `dt.timedelta(6)` subtracts 6 days from the df but there are missing days in the df so it doesn't provide the correct answer.

How can I slice `highP` so that it gives me the previous six values in that series for eg.

`highP.loc[i - 6: i].max()` given that `i` is a datetime index?

any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
upper_lower_bound = df[(isoHL['IH'] >= 1) | (isoHL['IL'] >= 1)].index[-3:-1]

if isoHL.loc[upper_lower_bound[-1]]['IH'] == 1 and isoHL.loc[upper_lower_bound[-1]]['IL'] == 0:
    upper_bound = highP.loc[upper_lower_bound[-1] - dt.timedelta(6):upper_lower_bound[-1]].max()
else:
    pass
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about sorting by time and taking last elements with tail?
For generality, I will use notations with:

- dataframe = `df`
- time column = `t`
- value column = `val`
- certain location = `i`

first we obtain a df of sample with time < time at `i`:

`before_df = df[df['t'] <= df.loc[i, 't']]`

then we sort by time:

`before_df = before_df.sort_values(by=['t'])`

then we take last five with 'tail':

`five_before = before_df.tail(5)`

then we max over value:

`val = five_before['val'].max()`

Does this solve your question?

`

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, I adjusted the code a little to what I have and works perfectly now! Much appreciated